# Помогите с решением задачи пожалуйста

Tags: c++, матрицы

Для заданной матрицы размером 8 на 8 найти такие k, что k-я строка матрицы совпадает с k-м столбцом. Найти сумму элементов в тех строках, которые содержат хотя бы один отрицательный элемент.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int** mas, n = 8, m = 8, i, j;
    mas = new int* [n];

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        mas[i] = new int[m];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {
            mas[i][j] = rand() % 10 - 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "isxodnyi massiv" << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < m; j++) cout << mas[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
```

Comment: Ну и где результаты **ваших** трудов над задачей? Или вы просто забыли волшебное слово "и быстро!"? :)

Comment: Все что смог-задать матрицу
ничего не соображаю
учеба
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int **mas, n = 8, m =8, i, j;
 mas = new int*[n];
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  mas[i] = new int[m];
 }
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
  {
   mas[i][j] = rand() % 10-1;
  }
 }
 cout << "isxodnyi massiv" << endl;
 for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
 {
  for (j = 0; j < m; j++)
   cout << mas[i][j] << "  ";
  cout << endl;
 }
 cout << endl;

Comment: Ладно, внес ваш код в вопрос за вас. Ну вот, уже кое-что. Несколько вопросов для следующего этапа - сколько всего строк/столбцов нужно сравнить для того, чтобы найти все `k` из условия? Что означает "строка совпадает со столбцом"? На последний вопрос лучше ответить и словами, и записать эти слова в виде кода. Ко второй части задачи перейдем попозже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
int main()
{   srand(time(0));
    int** mas, n = 8, m = 8;
    mas = new int* [n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   mas[i] = new int[m];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
        {   mas[i][j] = rand() % 10 - 1;
        }
    }

    cout << "isxodnyi massiv" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {   for (int j = 0; j < m; j++) cout << setw(4) << mas[i][j] << " ";

        cout << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;
    bool equal = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {   equal = true;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {   if (mas[i][j] != mas[j][i])
            {   equal = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (equal)
        {   cout << "k = " << i << endl;
        }
    }

    if (!equal)
    {   cout << "ravnyh stolbtsa i stroki net" << endl;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {   int sum = 0;
        bool negative = false;

        for (int j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {   sum += mas[i][j];

            if (mas[i][j] < 0) negative = true;
        }

        if (negative)
        {   cout << "stroka " << i << ": summa = " << sum << endl;
        }
    }
}
```